# How to restore sudo command after its having too many level of symlinks

Tags: command-line, bash, permissions, sudo, symbolic-link

I have done a terrible deed while linking javac to /usr/bin

I accidentally pasted wrong command line and now I cannot use sudo anymore and thus, I can't access any file or folder which needs permission.

It says

> bash: /usr/bin/sudo: Too many levels of symbolic links

The command line which I wrongly paseted is

```
sudo ln -f -s sudo ln -f -s /opt/jdk1.8.0_151/bin/javac /usr/bin
```

But it should be

```
sudo ln -f -s /opt/jdk1.8.0_151/bin/javac /usr/bin
```

But I already messed up. So, please, if anyone have any idea of how I can fix that, I'll be very thankful.

Comment: Updated my answer to try to su to root and see if that works.

Comment: Do you get a `grub` menu at boot time? You can start a root shell from there (recovery mode → root shell). The filesystems will be read-only at first but you can remount them read-write (`mount -o rw,remount /`) and then fix your broken `sudo`.

Answer (score 1):

Run the following to fix the error.

```
/usr/bin/sudo rm /usr/bin/javac
```

If the above line doesn't work, see if you can change to the `root` user then try again:

```
su root
rm /usr/bin/javac
```

Then rerun the correct line.

Hope this helps!

Comment: When I run your command line, terminal gives me this error :-  `~$ /usr/bin/sudo rm /usr/bin/javac
bash: /usr/bin/sudo: Too many levels of symbolic links
`

Comment: @BattleHawk That is interesting.  I ran your first command in a VM to test it out and that is what it took to fix it.  Turns out that sudo links to javac in the /usr/bin folder.  I would recommend then booting to a LiveCD and removing the javac link from the /usr/bin folder.

Comment: @BattleHawk Maybe follow some of the advice I gave in this answer to get the host booted to a LiveCD to fix it:  https://askubuntu.com/a/634013/231142

Comment: su root gives me this 

`~$ su root
Password: 
su: Authentication failure`